# button click action not responding in tableview ios

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I have a button in the footer of a tableview (list of videos) in xcode.
It shows a history (another viewcontroller) of all the videos the user has seen.
This button works but not after a refresh of the tableview data (so list of videos changes). When I restart the app it works again.
I also noticed that the IBaction is not a full round circel in xcode. Although I renewed the action already a few time.. (see screenshot)
Is there a way to use a button using code (like in javascript onclick) instead of relying on storyboard actions which seems unreliable to me?

[image: screenshot xcode]

Comment: Is the code executed when the button doesn't work?

Comment: Instead of sharing image of code. Please share code

Comment: some transparent View is overlaying your button look closely for any loose ends on constants plus try passing the footer without  .Nib

Comment: You call uiApplication top view controller to present history view : you should present view controller from the current view controller.

Comment: No the code is not executed when you press the button. Somehow the IBaction does not work after data update of the viewtable